# What does "c14n" mean?

Tags: xml, specifications, abbreviation, canonicalization, c14n

The [Canonical XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315) does not explain "c14n".
Is it an abbreviation or something?

- Cee-One-Four-En
- Leetspeak for clan

What does it stand for?

Comment: I think most the time when described as the numeronym, they'll pronounce `cee fourteen en`

Comment: @Matthew I wonder if i can say that in my next presentation. Kinda feels weird. But I also often have trouble saying "canonicalization".

Comment: Maybe, I think it depends on your audience.  I think if you say `c14n`, you'll have to at least say `canonicalization` once to describe it, as I wasn't familiar with what `c14n` meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c14n` is a [*numerical contraction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym#Numerical_contractions) for **canonicalization** — there are 14 characters between the `c` and the `n`. Numerical contractions are used beyond XML.

Another common numerical contraction is `i18n` for **internationalization**.

Answer (score 0):

**c14n is the abbreviation of Canonicalization.** It is used to make sure that our xml document is in a standard and consistent form.

**These kinds of abbreviations are like a commonly seen trend, it basically means that while abbreviating 14 letters were omitted between c and n**

The main aim of this is to make sure that semantically similar XML documents should have the same hash or signature.